# Connection error between Oracle Database 11g and Xero API

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, xero-api

We're using Xero API to connect our 11g database application with Xero. We're having an intermittent disconnection problem while trying to connect to Xero API.
We're using Apache 2.4 as a proxy by-pass sever.
The code we are executing is:

```
  declare
    g_access_token     clob;
    l_result           clob;
    l_status           varchar2(100);

  begin

    g_access_token := mis_xero_customer_api.get_access_token;

    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name  := 'Authorization';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'Bearer '||g_access_token;
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).name  := 'Accept';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).value := 'application/json';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(3).name  := 'Content-Type';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(3).value := 'application/json';

      l_result := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
        p_url            => 'http://localhost:80/xero-api-proxy/api.xro/2.0/Prepayments/1f0b5d92-3e2c-49fa-a8af-9867f0ef6019'
       ,p_http_method    => 'GET'
      );

    apex_json.parse(l_result);
    
    l_status := apex_json.get_varchar2('Prepayments[%d].Status',1);
    
    insert into temp_debug (col) values (l_status);commit;

  end;
```

The error message we receive is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request<p>Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
</body></html>
```

It only happens sometimes e.g., if I execute the code 2 3 times, then on the 3rd or 4th time we receive this response, and the moment after that, it connects again to the API.

Any advice or solutions to that? Would be happy to share more information.

Thanks.

Comment: "The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server." You need to fix the upstream server. If your code works apart from this occasional error then there is nothing wrong with your code.